# mv deleted my directory. Why?

Tags: linux, centos, filesystems

I was trying to correct the spelling on a directory, issued a *mv* command, and the directory is now gone. I'd like to understand--specifically--what happened.

Here's the command I ran:

```
mv micheal_franti_theme/ michael_franti_theme/
```

<strike>I understand there the slashes shouldn't be included: I was moving fast and used auto-complete.</strike>

The command ran without any errors or warnings. I tried using *find* for both the old and new spellings, but neither returned any results. So, what happened? What did *mv* actually do? Any chance of recovering the directory and its contents?

ext4 on CentOS 6.5; mv version 8.4

### Additional Info

Not sure why this is getting down votes.

There was a directory named "micheal_franti_theme". I ran the above command, then ran *ls*. No more directory.

No directory named "michael_franti_theme" existed anywhere on the file system when I ran that command.

As you can see from the command, the context is within the same sub-directory, so *mv* would have just updated the inode table (vs copying between file systems).

I ran the following:

```
sudo find / -name micheal_franti_theme
```

No results. The directory is gone

All commands posted in this question were copied directly from the command prompt.

I've been using Linux regularly for over a decade. I've never seen this happen before, so I'm bringing it to serverfault.

actual results are long gone from the scrollback buffer, but here are the relevant lines from *history*:

```
1097  ls
1098  mv micheal_franti_theme/ michael_franti_theme/
1099  ls
1100  find / -name michael_franti_theme 2>/dev/null
1101  find / -name micheal_franti_theme 2>/dev/null
1102  sudo find / -name michael_franti_theme
1103  sudo find / -name micheal_franti_theme
```

Comment: please leave a comment if you down vote. What's wrong with the question?

Comment: If you still have the command prompt open, you could copy the entire sequence of prompts, commands, and output into the question.

Comment: Try doing a "sudo find / -name michael_franti_theme -type d"

Comment: the commands from 30 min ago aren't in the terminal's scrollback buffer any more. However, I included my *exact* commands in my question

Comment: You may find the commands with `history`.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/259097/what-happens-if-mv-is-interrupted

Comment: haven't been able to recreate the behavior, so must've been interrupted or something like @l0sts0ck suggests (although inode table update should be atomic... but whatever)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I can get that command to run without errors is if both directories already exist. Or if only the source name exists.

If both directories do exist, what the command does is that it moves one directory into the other. So, you'll now have a directory named `michael_franti_theme/micheal_franti_theme`.

If only the source name exists, what the command does is a simple rename. So you'd have a directory named `michael_franti_theme`.

In both cases a directory named `michael_franti_theme` would exist after the rename. If more than one person is administrating this system, that directory could have been renamed again after the `mv` command but before running any `ls` or other command to look for the renamed directory.

It is also possible, that your current working directory wasn't what you think it was, and the files are somewhere else in the file system from where you are looking now.

Comment: only the micheal_franti_theme directory existed. Now, neither does. I figured the original just got moved (like you suggest), but "find" didn't find it anywhere in /

Comment: accepted as "could not reproduce" :)